# Alternative to INDIRECT() that would not be affected by adding/deleting coloumns

Tags: google-sheets

when trying to do some conditional formatting in Google Sheets, I've got a column(Q) whose values should be color RED if column M = "QS" and itself is a date in the past.

I've got the formuala working perfectly, but it looks like I have to use the INDIRECT() function. The problem I have is that when I add or delete columns in the sheet, the formula breaks as the references to columns were absolute references. Does anyone have any better ideas?

```
=AND(SEARCH("QS", INDIRECT("M"&ROW())), INDIRECT("Q"&ROW())<TODAY())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why doesn't

```
=AND(L1 = "QS", Q1 < TODAY())
```

Work for you?* It keeps the formatting intact for me when adding or deleting columns.

<sub>* Assuming your data to be formatted starts at Q1</sub>

Comment: Because when it is applied to range, Q2;Q271 each row in Q would look at the values in row 1 instead of their respective row

Comment: It doesn't If you apply the exact formula above to Q2:271 the reference in the formula will behave like any relative reference and change

Comment: Starting at q2 you would use `=AND(L2 = "QS", Q2 < TODAY())` to be precise

Comment: Thanks Robin, it worked. It didn't seem logical to me. The row number in formula must match the first row in the specified range.